# Как подключиться к гугл таблице по id. Модуль gspread_asyncio. Python

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet, асинхронность, gspread

Пишу асинхронный парсер, в котором нужно подключиться к гугл таблице и забрать некоторые данные. Когда не использовал асинхронность, всегда пользовался обычным gspread, но в асинхронности интерпретатор ругался на его методы. Нашел модуль gspread_asyncio, только возникли трудности с подключением. Пожалуйста, помогите!

Comment: Идете в доку https://gspread-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, копируете пример из введения. Заменяете `create()` на `open_by_key()` или `open_by_url()`. Готово!